# Racket dice function

Tags: racket

I code a function to roll dnd's dice :

```
(define (rnd [n 0] [d 0] [li '()] [count 0])
  (cond [(= n 0) '()]
        [(= count n) (values li (foldl + 0 li))]
        [(< count n) (rnd n d (cons (random 1 (+ d 1)) li) (+ count 1))]))
```

But I always feel this code was ugly.
Have idea to improve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplified version:

```
(define (rnd [n 0] [d 1] [li '()])
  (if (<= n 0)
      (values li (foldl + 0 li))
      (rnd (- n 1) d (cons (random 1 (+ d 1)) li))))
```

Note that the default value of `d` is `1` instead of zero, otherwise the function does not work with just one argument.